# KeyError: 'filename' while linking python and html using karrigell

Tags: html, python-2.7, cgi

I'm trying to read an uploaded file using python 2.7 and Karrigell. But it is showing me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Karrigell-3.1.1\karrigell\core\HTTP.py", line 333, in process_request
  File "C:\Karrigell-3.1.1\karrigell\core\k_target.py", line 399, in run
  File "", line 7, in 
  File "cgi.pyc", line 541, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'filename'
```

Here is my web_access.py:

```
import cgi, os

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem=form['filename']
if fileitem.file:
    print fileitem.file.read()

else:
    print "Error"
```

My Html page:

```
<section>
    Enter the text: 
    <form action="web_access.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filename" id="file" value="" size="50"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Analyze"/>
    </form>
</section>
```

Help me out please!

Answer (score 0):

With Karrigell you don't need to use the CGI module ; you get a reference to form fields as keys of the built-in object `REQUEST`

web_access.py could be something like

```
print REQUEST['filename'].file.read()
```

This is documented [here](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/en/fileuploads.html)